# How do I refactor (fix) this method?

Tags: typescript, oop, types, interface, dynamically-generated

I'm new with typescript and I kept getting the same "not assignable to parameter of type error" error, and, after some research, I solve it but I'm not proud of the solution.

I'm working with a simple class and to simplify I let only the attribute I'm working with.

```
interface Proficiencies {
  armor: string[];
  weapons: string[];
  tools: string[];
  savingThrows: number[];
  skills: boolean[];
}

interface ProfAndBonus extends Proficiencies {
  bonus: number
}
```

```
class Character {
  public readonly proficiencies: ProfAndBonus = {
      bonus: 2,
      armor: [],
      weapons: [],
      tools: [],
      savingThrows: [],
      skills: []
    }

// This is the code that have the error
public addProficiency<T extends keyof Proficiencies> (proficiencyType: T, proficiency: Proficiencies[T]) {
    this.proficiencies[proficiencyType].push(...proficiency);
  }
}
```

If I add 'as never[]' it works, but I wonder if there's any other way to make it transpile.

```
this.proficiencies[proficiencyType].push(...proficiency as never[]);
```

**EDIT** 
The answers you gave me worked perfectly but I found out that the error was because of the '*ProfAndBonus*' interface that I don't show to simplify.

Comment: Why do you try to change the value of `proficiencies` while you made it `readonly`?

Comment: Because I don't change `proficiencies` it self, I change the lists content inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental issue is that you haven't made it "explicit enough" that every property of `Proficiencies` is an array of some type, where that type varies with the key. In `addProficiency`, `this.proficiencies[proficiencyType]` has type `Proficiencies[T]`. When Typescript looks for a `push` method on this object, it needs to simplify it to something it can do method lookup on. Right now, it can't think of anything better to do except *union* all the types of the fields of `Proficiencies` and say it has a `string[] | number[] | boolean[]`. Then Typescript knows this object must have a `push` method, but it isn't sure if that `push` takes `...items: string[]` or `number[]` or `boolean[]`, so plays it safe and says it takes `...items: never[]` (which means it isn't useful).

You need to give Typescript a way to say that `Proficiencies[T]` is always `Something<T>[]`. Then, without needing to simplify `Something<T>`, Typescript can say the `push` method takes `...items: Something<T>[]`. Then, since this is now depending on `T`, it is possible to call `push` with a parameter of the right type.

You can do this by adding a helper type to map between keys and the *element types* of the arrays.

```
interface ProficiencyTypes {
    armor: string
    weapons: string
    tools: string
    savingThrows: number
    skills: boolean
}
type MapArray<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: T[Key][]
}
type Proficiencies = MapArray<ProficiencyTypes> // teach typescript "every key of Proficiencies is a key of ProficiencyTypes but with [] added to its type"
class Character {
  public readonly proficiencies: Proficiencies = {
    armor: [],
    weapons: [],
    tools: [],
    savingThrows: [],
    skills: []
  }
  public addProficiency<T extends keyof Proficiencies>(proficiencyType: T, proficiency: Proficiencies[T]) {
    this.proficiencies[proficiencyType].push(...proficiency);
  }
}
```

Note that now you can't add non-array properties to `Proficiencies`. That is *exactly* the freedom that Typescript wants/needs you to give up in order to ensure a function like `addProficiency` makes sense. In the case of `ProfWithBonus`, where there *is* an extra property, you need to first upcast `this.proficiencies` to just the mapped type (i.e. assure Typescript you won't try to operate on the non-array properties).

```
interface ProfAndBonus extends Proficiencies {
  bonus: number
}
class Character {
  public readonly proficiencies: ProfAndBonus  = {
    bonus: 2,
    armor: [],
    weapons: [],
    tools: [],
    savingThrows: [],
    skills: []
  }
  public addProficiency<T extends keyof Proficiencies>(proficiencyType: T, proficiency: Proficiencies[T]) {
    let proficiencies: Proficiencies = this.proficiencies
    proficiencies[proficiencyType].push(...proficiency);
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, but I don't realize that the mistake was at another part of the code, please review the edited problem. Thank you again for answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Your mistake is here:

```js
    public readonly proficiencies: Proficiencies = {
          armor: [],
          weapons: [],
          tools: [],
          savingThrows: [],
          skills: []
        }
```

Without defining the array type, it by default will be `never`. So when you tried to add a `...proficiency` to it, it was a type mismatch, and so it threw the error you saw.

Furthermore, you define `proficiencies` as an object while you try to call the `push` method which is available on `arrays`!

#### Your code :

```js
    interface Proficiencies {
      armor: string[];
      weapons: string[];
      tools: string[];
      savingThrows: number[];
      skills: boolean[];
    }
    
    class Character implements Proficiencies {
      armor: string[] = [];
      weapons: string[] = [];
      tools: string[] = [];
      savingThrows: number[] = [];
      skills: boolean[] = [];
      
      public readonly proficiencies: Proficiencies = {
        armor: this.armor,
        weapons: this.weapons,
        tools: this.tools,
        savingThrows: this.savingThrows,
        skills: this.skills,
      };
      
      public addProficiency<T extends keyof Proficiencies>(
        proficiencyType: T,
        proficiency: Proficiencies[T]
      ) {
        return [this.proficiencies, ...proficiency];
      }
    }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly too, but as I said to the other answer I did not realize that the mistake was at another part of the code, please review the edited problem. Thank you again for taking the time helping me.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, The bool type is not a valid type in TypeScript. You should use the boolean type instead.

```
  interface Proficiencies {
  armor: string[];
  weapons: string[];
  tools: string[];
  savingThrows: number[];
  skills: boolean[]; <----
}
```

**Second**, the proficiency parameter type is not being inferred correctly by TypeScript, causing the error you're seeing. Please try like this:

```
 public addProficiency<T extends keyof Proficiencies, U extends Proficiencies[T]>(
      proficiencyType: T,
      proficiency: U
    ) {
      this.proficiencies[proficiencyType].push(...proficiency);
    }
```

Comment: I made the first mistake when writing the example for the question, thank you tough.
I tried the second answer and I got the same error as before, it does not fix it.